# ckEditor inline editing toolbar configuration

Tags: ckeditor

I have two sets of toolbar configured in the config.js file.

One set is a basic tool bar and another one is complete tool bar.

For one text area alone I want to load the complete tool bar set and I'm doing that via the below code.

`CKEDITOR.inline('textareaAppendix', [CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = ToolBarComplete]);`

But even for this TextArea "textareaAppendix" the basic tool bar is loaded instead of the complete one. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. I solved it. A small change

```
 CKEDITOR.inline('textareaAppendix', {
        toolbar: 'ToolBarComplete'
    });
```

And now for this TextArea "textareaAppendix" alone I can load the complete tool bar.